# Question about CSS float:left

Tags: css

```
   <div style="width: 800px;border:1px solid black">
          <div style="width:100px;height:100px;float:left;border:1px solid black"></div>
          <div style="float:left">ssdfsdfsdfsdgfag25w6a4g8w5614w5sge16dgf45d4sdffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff5s4f64s6f456a46f456a456456456f456we4f54we5gf45456v4sd5646sadf54s56f465as4f564as56f</div>
          <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
```

It end up like this: 
[image]
how to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put a width on the 2nd child div. you will also need to put a space in that string as it cannot wrap it across lines.

```
 <div style="width: 800px;border:1px solid black">
          <div style="width:100px;height:100px;float:left;border:1px solid black"></div>
          <div style="float:left; width: 100px">ssdfsdfsdfsdgfag25w6a4g8w5614w5sge16dgf45d4sdffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff5s4f64s6f456a46f456a456456456f456we4f54we5gf45456v4sd5646sadf54s56f465as4f564as56f</div>
          <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set height to 100 to for main div

Comment: i dont want set height for main div